# Spring Data JPA saving two entities at the same time, null value in column "user_id"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have users in my application and users have work details, I use one method to set the user/work details data and then I either add a new user or modify an existing one.

This is the method for setting user/work data:

```
public WorkDetail setWorkerData(PatchWorkerRequest request, User user, WorkDetail workDetail) {

        if (request.getName() != null) {
            user.setName(request.getName());
        }

        if (request.getIdCode() != null) {
            user.setIdCode(request.getIdCode());
        }

        if (request.getEmail() != null) {
            user.setEmail(request.getEmail());
        }

        if (request.getPhone() != null) {
            user.setPhone(request.getPhone());
        }

        if (request.getAddress() != null) {
            user.setAddress(request.getAddress());
        }

        if (request.getSignatureLevel() != null) {
            user.setSignatureLevel(request.getSignatureLevel());
        }

        if (request.getAltContactRelation() != null) {
            user.setAltContactRelation(request.getAltContactRelation());
        }

        if (request.getAltContactPhone() != null) {
            user.setAltContactPhone(request.getAltContactPhone());
        }

        if (request.getRoles() != null) {
            user.setRoles(request.getRoles());
        }

        if (request.getStatus() != null) {
            user.setStatus(request.getStatus());
        }

        // Work details

        if (request.getJobRelation() != null) {
            workDetail.setJobRelation(request.getJobRelation());
        }

        if (request.getSalary() != null) {
            workDetail.setSalary(request.getSalary());
        }

        if (request.getDistricts() != null) {
            workDetail.setDistricts(request.getDistricts());
        }

        if (request.getCompetences() != null) {
            workDetail.setCompetences(request.getCompetences());
        }

        workDetail.setUser(user);
        user.setWorkDetail(workDetail);

        return workDetailRepository.save(workDetail);
    }
```

Now, modifying an existing worker works fine with this code:

```
public WorkDetail modifyWorker(Long workerId, PatchWorkerRequest request) {
        WorkDetail workDetail = this.getWorkDetailById(workerId);
        User user = userService.getUserById(workDetail.getUser().getId());
        return setWorkerData(request, user, workDetail);
    }
```

But when I try to create a new user/worker I get an error that `"null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint"`. I assume it's because the workDetail and user don't get connected properly.

This is the method for creating a new worker:

```
public WorkDetail createWorker(PatchWorkerRequest request) {
        WorkDetail workDetail = new WorkDetail();
        User user = new User();
        String generatedPassword = userService.generatePassword(8);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(generatedPassword));
        emailService.sendMail("SYDA", new String[]{request.getEmail()},
                "Project SYDA",
                "New password: " + generatedPassword + ".);
        return setWorkerData(request, user, workDetail);
    }
```

Also, is there any way I could send the email after saving the user so in case of errors it wouldn't send the email?

Entities:

User:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
})
@Table(name = "user_acc")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "id_code")
    private BigInteger idCode;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private BigInteger phone;

    @Column(name = "alt_contact_relation")
    private String altContactRelation;

    @Column(name = "alt_contact_phone")
    private BigInteger altContactPhone;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createTime = new Date();

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    private Date updateTime = new Date();

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "active_status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
    private UserStatus status;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @JsonIgnore
    private WorkDetail workDetail;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserFile> userFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "signature_level_id")
    private SignatureLevel signatureLevel;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = UserRole.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_user_role",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Mechanism.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_mechanism",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "mechanism_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private Set<Mechanism> mechanisms = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Service.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_service",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "service_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private Set<Service> services = new HashSet<>();

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void onCreateOnUpdate() {
        updateTime = new Date();
    }

    public enum UserStatus {
        active, temporarily_inactive, inactive
    }
}
```

WorkDetail:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "work_detail")
public class WorkDetail {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private float salary;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "workDetail",fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date createTime = new Date();

    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date updateTime = new Date();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "workDetail")
    private List<UserLeave> userLeaves = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_relation_id")
    private JobRelation jobRelation;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = District.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "work_detail_has_district",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "work_detail_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "district_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private Set<District> districts = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Competence.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "work_detail_has_competence",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "work_detail_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "competence_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private Set<Competence> competences = new HashSet<>();

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void onCreateOnUpdate() {
        updateTime = new Date();
    }
}
```

Db tables:

```
-----------------------
-- User table
-----------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_acc (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name text NOT NULL,
  id_code numeric NOT NULL,
  email text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  address text NULL,
  alt_contact_relation text NULL,
  alt_contact_phone numeric NULL,
  signature_level_id integer NULL,
  username text NOT NULL,
  password text NOT NULL,
  create_time TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  update_time TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  status active_status NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
  CONSTRAINT FK_user_signature_level FOREIGN KEY (signature_level_id) REFERENCES signature_level (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

-----------------------
-- User: work detail table
-----------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS work_detail (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  salary decimal NULL,
  job_relation_id integer NOT NULL,
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  create_time TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  update_time TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_work_detail_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_acc (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_work_details_job_relations1 FOREIGN KEY (job_relation_id)
    REFERENCES job_relation (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Comment: would u please add the definition of `User` as well as `WorkDetail` Entity Class Definition. @Heiko

Comment: @VikrantKashyap added the entities

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the `user` before you add it to the `workDetail`. The new `User` object does not have an id, and that is why you are getting that exception.
Something like this:

```
public WorkDetail createWorker(PatchWorkerRequest request) {
        WorkDetail workDetail = new WorkDetail();
        User user = new User();
        String generatedPassword = userService.generatePassword(8);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(generatedPassword));
        user = userRepository.save(user);
        emailService.sendMail("SYDA", new String[]{request.getEmail()},
                "Project SYDA",
                "New password: " + generatedPassword + ".);
        return setWorkerData(request, user, workDetail);
    }
```

or you can add a `saveUser` call inside the `setWorkerData` method.

```
...
 if (request.getStatus() != null) {
            user.setStatus(request.getStatus());
        }
user = userRepository.save(user);
...
```

Comment: Hmmm... now the first time it says the same error: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint.

But when I run the request again on postman I get that the user by the given email already exists. After checking the database the user indeed created, but It's not connected to WorkDetail.

Comment: Where did you insert the `user = userRepository.save(user);` line? The user that is returned from the `userRepository.save(user)` method will always have an id. So this should be done before you do `workDetail.setUser(user);`

Comment: I inserted it as you showed. Setting the user comes after saving the user.

Comment: Can you check that the `user` object has id before calling `   workDetail.setUser(user);` ? Add a print statement or a debug point at that call.

Comment: You can also try removing the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` on the user object inside the WorkDetail entity.

Answer (score 1):

In your `setWorker()` method you try to set `user` for `workDetail` Object but `user` Object doesn't have their `user_id` because this user object is detached mode and still no `user_id` is associated with user Object.

```
 //some code in your setWorker() Method.
 workDetail.setUser(user);   //you try to set a detached User Object which doesn't have it's id.
 user.setWorkDetail(workDetail);

 return workDetailRepository.save(workDetail);
```

So, either save that `user` just before setting and make sure `user` Object is persisted into database .

add this line before above code..

```
user = userRepository.save(user); // add this line....
workDetail.setUser(user);   //now your User Object will have it's id.
user.setWorkDetail(workDetail);

return workDetailRepository.save(workDetail);
```

there is also a another way to perform this without calling `save()` method just by using the concept of **cascading** for more info go through with this [Link Here](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/)

Comment: I tried adding the line, I still get that user_id constraint error, but the user is inserted to the database. Now I'm just confused :D

Comment: sorry my bad.. you should re-initialize user just by saving the object such that user_id made available to workDetail Object..

add this line `user = userRepository.save(user); `

Comment: @HeikoPiirme  Now my answer is updated... please go through with this...

Comment: I added the "user =" before already. I even used System.out.println(user.toString()); after saving it to see, if the ID is there. The Id is there, but it still gives me the "user_id" constraint problem. After trying to send the same request again I get that the user already exists.

It adds the user to the database, but doesn't set workDetails user to the user I just created.

Comment: please make sure your foreign key constraint in database that you made is correct... because it's it seems your Entity class configuration doesn't support Your table constrainsts...

Comment: I added the tables in the original post, seems fine to me, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spring-boot-starter-mail dependency to get this work

Comment: The email works fine. The email gets sent, but the user doesn't get saved in the repository.

Comment: Can you please provide the .save() method for an additional look @HeikoPiirme

Comment: The save method is default on Spring repositories

Answer (score 0):

It means the user object is not saved when you try to save the workdetail object.
So there is not user_id to put, hence the null value.
Could should post you entities please ? (specially the mapping between them).
I think, you should have something like `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)` if you want you save both entities at the same time.

Comment: Added entities to the original post, when I patch the user/workdetail it saves both at the same time

Comment: you posted twice the User entity

Comment: did you try to :

     `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "workDetail", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;`

Comment: Doesn't change anything, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is wrong.
Here's what you should do :
in WorkDetail :
 `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
 @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") 
 private User user;`

in User :
  `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user") 
 @JsonIgnore 
 private WorkDetail workDetail;`